# Derivative with Chain Rule of Sum of Squares Error Function when fitting the data using Mth order polynomial

Tags: calculus, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

This is from the very first exercise of Chris Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*. The questions asks us to show how minimizing the Sum-of-Squares Error Function through the weights **w** is the same as solving a linear set of equations he presents to us. I understand we must take the derivative of the error function with respect to **w**, set it to zero, and then inevitably expand it out and show it takes the form of the linear set of equations he presents. Note that $y(x_n, \pmb{w}) = w_0 + w_1 x + w_2 x^2 ...w_{M}x^M = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{M} w_jx^j$

However, I am stuck on the Chain rule portion of taking the derivative of $E(w) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \{ y(x_n,\pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2$.

Right now, I have...

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial E(\pmb{w})}{\partial \pmb{w}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{w}} \frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2
\end{align}

We can push the derivative through the sum, since the sum of the derivative is equivalent to the derivative of the sum.
\begin{align*}
    & = \frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{w}} \{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \}^2
\end{align*}
By the chain rule.
\begin{align*}
    & = \frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2 \{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \} (\frac{\partial y(x_n, \pmb{w})}{\partial \pmb{w}})
\end{align*}

Now my issue is evaluating $(\frac{\partial y(x_n, \pmb{w})}{\partial \pmb{w}})$. This is equivalent to

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{w}} \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{M} w_jx^j
\end{align}

Which I see as equalling

\begin{align}
 = \sum_{j=1}^{M} x^j
\end{align}

So then, the derivative of the Error function would be

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2 \{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \} (\sum_{j=1}^{M} x^j)
\end{align}

However, all the solutions I've seen have the derivative of the Error function as being
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2 \{ y(x_n, \pmb{w}) - t_n \} x_n^i
\end{align}

Which does result in the correct answer. So my question is, where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $w$ here is a vector and hence the outcome is going to be a vector.

For example, let $w \in \mathbb{R}^2$, that is $M=1$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_0}\left( w_0+w_1x\right)=1=x^0 \ne x^0+x^1$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_1}\left( w_0+w_1x\right)=x=x^1 \ne x^0+x^1$$

Edit:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & x_1^1 & \ldots & x_1^M\\\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_N^1 & \ldots & x_N^M \end{bmatrix}$, $w= \begin{bmatrix}w_0 \\ \vdots\\ w_M \end{bmatrix}$, and $t=\begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ \vdots\\ t_N \end{bmatrix}$.

$$E(w)=\frac12 \|Aw-t\|^2$$

$$\nabla E(w) = A^T(Aw-t)=0$$

$$A^TAw = A^Tt$$

Comment: I see. So, can another way of putting this be: $\sum_{j=0}^M = w_jx_n^j$ per the prompt. We want to take the derivative of this (in the step that I was confused about). To reframe that sum, it is equivalent to $(w_0, w_1,...w_M)^T \cdot (1,x_n,x_n^2,...x_n^M)$. Therefore, when we take the derivative of that expression with respect to the vector $w = (w_0, w_1,...w_M)$, we simply get $(1,x_n,x_n^2,...x_n^M)$.

Comment: yup, the wiki page of [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) might be of interest.